# Sending an array of objects to server via ajax (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a series of entries retrieved from an html table.

> E.g. (1, 123), (1,234), (2, 134) …etc

I want to send these via JQuery ajax call to the server but I am not sure how to create the corresponding json call.
How can I do this?

I don't know how to form the array.
I know I should use something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'path/getdetails.html',
   data : {
       'a'     : value,
       'b'    : value,                                                                                                                                      
    }, 
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
```

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: I don't know how to form the array.
I know I should use something like:  
 `$.ajax({
      url: 'path/getdetails.html',
       data : {
           'a'     : value,
           'b'    : value,    }, 
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',`

Comment: @Jim can you show your code kindly

Comment: @Backtrack:This is it. I am trying to figure out how to write it by googling

Comment: @Jim  i have  updated my answer have a look

Answer (score 2):

This is my table

```
<table id="students" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="student">
            <td>Oscar</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>16.5</td>        
        </tr>
        <tr class="student">
            <td>Antonio</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>14</td>        
        </tr>
        <tr class="student">
            <td>Jessica</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>19</td>        
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>​​​​​​
```

and my java script look like this

```
     function send() {
            var value = $('#students tr:has(td)').map(function(i, v) {
    var $td =  $('td', this);
        return {
                 id: ++i,
                 name: $td.eq(0).text(),
                 age: $td.eq(1).text(),
                 grade: $td.eq(2).text()               
               }
}).get();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/test/PersonSubmit',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:JSON.stringify(values),
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#target').html(data.msg);
                },

            });
        }
```

hope this will help you

Comment: How do you define the `values`?

Comment: @Jim On the top line of your post, it seems you said you had extracted the values out of a table and into an array.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: @Paul:It is from a table yes

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your **array of objects** is

```
var postData =  [{"key1": 123}, {"key2": 234}, {"key3": 134}]
```

Use `JSON.stringify` for your data and content type of `application/json`in your ajax call.

Like this

```
contentType: 'application/json'
data: JSON.stringify(postData)
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I don't know how to define the data

Comment: @Jim you can define your array of objects as above

Comment: Why do you need to stringify it rather than just send it through as raw JSON

Comment: His *array of objects* doesnt look like json objects .. so just so that the application gets proper data. I edited the answer later since the data definition was his problem

Comment: @Jim your array of objects doesnt look like objects .. does this answer help ?

Comment: Darn! I actually have 3 attributes to bind together

Comment: If its not helpful could just remove it .. let me know if i misunderstood